# Two mappings for one database table

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to find a solution for an architectural error and I'm not the architect :P

Is there the possibility to have two mappings for the same table in Hibernate3? The first one would have some lazy attributes set to true. The second mapping would ha some lazy attributes set to false; besides, mappings are equals. I know, it is a strange and bizarre behaviour, but the customer asks for a quick solution.

Comment: do you really need a second mapping or can you just set the fetch lazy to true/false when you fetch your entity?

Comment: I think a second mapping is needed because two different scenarios: the same entity is read by online and batch processes. The online process has already designed its mapping, where lazy is set to false. For a batch process that's a problem, because lazy=false causes reading of all the hierarchy; that's a big problem on long tasks. This is the architectural problem: is possible to have a second mapping (where lazy is set to true) to avoid changing the "online mapping"? Thanks for your help, bertolami.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, there's no reason why not, but you should be careful. The hibernate cache (session and L2 caches) will treat them as distinct, so if you manipulate the table row using both mappings in the same session, you run the risk of data loss, since hibernate won't know they're referring to the same underlying data.

Answer (score 0):

The very quick solution would be to have 2 different classes mapped to the same table.